# SkyDrive Pro and on-premises SharePoint 2010

Tags: office

I've just installed the final version of Office Professional Plus 2013 from MSDN and had a play with SkyDrive Pro. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to synchronize with a library our on premise SharePoint 2010. In actual fact the library is actually with Project Server installed on top of SharePoint, but I don't think that should be a difference?

```
http://sharepoint.xxx.com/pwa/My Library
```

I get the following error message on the Task Tray icon:

SkyDrive Pro - Sync problems

When I view sync problems I get:

"We’re having trouble downloading this file. It may be too large or there may be a network connectivity problem. Please try again later."

This is externally accessible on:

```
http://sharepoint.xxx.com
```

and internally on:

```
http://sharepoint
```

Neither work.

I have followed the suggestions in this post to no avail:

http://blog.hametbenoit.info/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=405#.UI6NLMVWx8E

Thanks,

Mike Taylor

Comment: How large are the files in that library?

Comment: Not very, just Word documents really.

Comment: 156 Kb DOCX is the largest really.

Comment: Anyone got any ideas here? I tried it on a Library in the route SharePoint site and I got the same problem. So I think that rules out Project Server?

Comment: I have no idea how, but its recently started working fine. I'd be interested to know if anyone has any ideas on this?

Comment: If you no longer have the problem, and there is not likely to be an explanation for the behaviour, it might be best to close this question.

Comment: sky drive pro will only sync with the SP2013 and not with SP2010

Answer (score 1):

Check this post by Gokan Ozcifci...

http://gokanx.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/skydrive-pro-is-not-supported-with-sharepoint-2010/.

I would suggest you to rollback to SharePoint Workspace 2010 which just work :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the sky drive pro only takes the sync from Sharepoint 2013 . 
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blog/Pages/BlogPost.aspx?pID=1033

Comment: You guess wrong. Please read the entire post before answering. As I said, it started working OK a while back.